# Check if location is in bounds

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am using `Android studio` and trying to create an application which uses `Google Maps V2`. I have got the map running well with the `API Key`.
I will be adding a couple of `markers` to the `map`. I want to add the `markers` in such a way that they will add only if they are in a specific `radius` of the users current `location`. Is there any method to check if the `marker` comes in the `radius` or not? And how do we add the `radius` for the map?

Comment: what have you done yet . show your code please . this is long answer.

Comment: I have got the locations of the markers and stored them in my database. I am really not sure about how to proceed further. If you could only tell me how to make sure those markers come inside the radius, that will be more than enough.

Comment: do you have a radius ? how do you get it ?

Comment: That is my problem. I am not sure how we get the radius. Is there any method or maybe some library?

Comment: nope . ok tell me do you have a latlng or point from which you want to calculate radius ?

Comment: I have latlng. Thank you so much for this by the way

Comment: Is there somewhere i can contact you, since this comment section is extending a lot. I really need this to work.

Comment: read about google maps api, google directions api . this will be enough . you will surely get what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone wanders upon this, here is what I did.
There is a method in Location known as distanceBetween().
This is the documentation for the method. You might find distanceTo () useful too. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html
Scroll down to find the method.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use:

`LatLngBounds bounds = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
bounds.contains(your_bounds)`

This will check if `your_bounds` are cointined inside `bounds`